# Bold upright i-hat and j-hat for vector notation

Tags: math-mode, bold, accents

I am trying to typeset a vector with i-hat and j-hat components:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\ihat}{\mathbf {\hat \imath}}
\newcommand{\jhat}{\mathbf {\hat \jmath}}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf #1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \vect{F} &= 3\ihat + 4\jhat
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

However, `\imath` and `\jmath` will always be italicized, no matter what modifiers I apply `\mathbf`, `\mathrm`, etc.

How do I make `\imath` and `\jmath` **bold** and upright?

Comment: The `\mathrm` command has no effect on `\imath` or `\jmath`. LaTeX is smart enough to remove the dot on the **i** or **j** when adding a hat.

Comment: Use bold roman for `\jmath` in latex command.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For **bold** *and* upright, you could use the regular text-version of `\imath` and `\jmath`, which are `\i` and `\j`:

```
\newcommand{\ihat}{\hat{\textbf{\i}}}
\newcommand{\jhat}{\hat{\textbf{\j}}}
```

[image: bold & upright i & j in math]

Additionally, if you want the `\hat` to be bold as well, then use `\boldsymbol`.

```
\newcommand{\ihat}{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{\i}}}}
\newcommand{\jhat}{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{\j}}}}
```

[image: Now with bold \hat]

Comment: Both these work for me as you described when converting Markdown to PDF with Pandoc (LaTeX/math in Markdown marked off with $$). But it won’t convert to Word. Removing the \ before the `i` or `j` results in the conversion working, but the dots are back. Any ideas? Should I ask somewhere else?

Comment: @lukejanicke: I don't know what might be happening converting to Word. Perhaps another math font is used that doesn't have that dotless symbol. Try adding `\usepackage{dotlessi}` to your preamble (as part of `header-includes`).

Comment: I'm currently drafting in Markdown with embedded LaTeX/math but if I have more similar issues I may consider starting to draft in full TeX/LaTeX and then I can try your suggestion. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 18):

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ii}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\jj}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"11}

\newcommand{\ihat}{\mathbf {\hat{\ii}}}
\newcommand{\jhat}{\mathbf {\hat{\jj}}}
\newcommand{\vect}{\mathbf}
```

The last line is a better definition of your `\vect` command.

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer worked where Werner's did not, for my document that uses non-CM text fonts (where `\j` was not defined).

Comment: `\boldsymbol` is better than `\mathbf`  for vectors.

Comment: @skvery That's a personal style choice. The OP seems to prefer `\mathbf`.

Comment: @egreg Not _really._   The ISO standard specifies 'bold italic'. Can you maybe assist with my question using your answer.

Comment: @skvery The ISO standard is mandatory for some fields, mainly technical. Certainly not for pure mathematics. I have happily used upright bold for many years and the ISO police hasn't yet caught me. ;-)

Comment: @egreg my challenge: upright `\jmath` in MathJax, lol.

Comment: @skvery The main problem is that the people at Unicode didn't think to a bold dotless j. Why? Don't ask me.

Answer (score 3):

```
\newcommand{\ihat}{\textbf{\^\i}}
\newcommand{\jhat}{\textbf{\^\j}}
```

This is a simplification of Werner's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use it, the `unicode-math` package declares the `\mathbfup` alphabet, or `\symbfup`.  For single letters, the difference is not important.  If you load one of the math fonts that comes in a bold version (As of 2019, XITS Math, Libertinus Math or Minion Math), `\boldsymbol` will still work.

Answer (score 0):

You can define in your preamble a new command with an optional parameter, which would be the letter you want to hat. This could be something like

```
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\textbf{\^{#1}}}
```

where you must put the command in the form `\uvec{\yourletter}`. The "\" before the letter is necessary in order to avoid the i's and j's dots. For example, if you want to type the unit vector in x direction you must use `\uvec{\i}` or `$\uvec{\i}$`. This command works in both text and math mode and gives the same results. Also is for every letter, not only i or j.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work. Please test it again and show an example how to use your proposal.

Comment: What is the `\text` command suppose to do here? (hint: not needed, might even be rather bad, chech what happens if the text context outside math is italic. If I'm not mistaken vecbf will then also be italic

Comment: You're right daleif, in this new update I simplified the command and expanded the explanation a little bit.