# Math mode problem

Tags: math-mode

I'm completely new to LaTeX, and I'm just learning how to type math equations. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
The position of an object is given by
$\textbf{r} = (\emph{ct - bt^3}) \textbf{\hat{i}}$ + 
$\emph{dt^2}/textbf${\hat{j}}$, with constants \emph{c} = 6.7 m/s,
\emph{b} = 0.81 m/s^3, and \emph{d} = 4.5 m/s^2.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In its current form, it's hard to tell what is being asked in the question. You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The environments like \textbf and \emph are not suited for being using inside of a math formula. Use \mathbf for the bolds inside your formulae, the characters inside of the formula are italic by default.

Comment: Also, keep the plus sign within the math code, you don' t need to close and open again the math mode. `$.... + ....$`.

Comment: Also use an appropriate package for writing units, e.g., `siunitx`. You would write $b = 0.81 \si{\metre\per\cubic\second}$.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome, to the site and to LaTeX!

Well, the number one thing I cannot stress enough is not to skip in and out of math mode. This is a very common mistake, so don't feel bad about it, but math mode (`$ ... $`) doesn't mean 'mathify' this, and it isn't primarily a way of getting special characters (although many commands only work in math mode). It's designed for typesetting the entire mathmatical object. Thus all of this:

```
$\textbf{r} = (\emph{ct - bt^3}) \textbf{\hat{i}}$ + 
$\emph{dt^2}/textbf${\hat{j}}$
```

Should be within one pair of `$ ... $`. LaTeX's math mode is designed to give you the correct spacing around operators such as `+` and `=`, don't circumvent this.

I don't know if `/textbf${\hat{j}}` is a typo for `\textbf${\hat{j}}` (i.e. you have `/` but you meant `\`) or whether you left out the `\`: `/\textbf${\hat{j}}`

`$` must not come between `\textbf` and `{`.

Using `\textbf{}` in math mode is not exactly *wrong* in this case, but it is a bit counter-intuitive. Try `\mathbf{}`

Using `\emph` within math mode is definitely wrong. `\emph{}` is used within text to emphasise it. By default, `\emph{}` italicises text, but it is not an all-purpose italicisation command. `$ ... $` italicises characters by default and the usual problem people have is making things not italicised! It is also a text mode command, which means math mode commands like `^` will not work within `\emph{}` unless you enter math mode again, totally circumventing the `\emph{}` in this circumstance, i.e.: `\emph{foo $bar^{baz}$}`.

`\hat{i}` will give you an i with a hat over the tittle. Having it bold, and dotless, and with a hat, is a much more difficult task than it may look. Ordinarily, you'd want to use `\hat{\imath}`, but then it would not be bold. Using `\mathbf{}` won't make it bold, but loading the `bm` package and using `\bm{\hat{\imath}}` will make it bold, but then it won't be upright, it'll be italic.

So, I used this question:

[Bold upright i-hat and j-hat for vector notation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28210/bold-upright-i-hat-and-j-hat-for-vector-notation)

As mentioned above, `^` must be used in math mode. `\emph{b} = 0.81 m/s^3` will fail.

Also, avoid using `\emph{}` for variables, use math mode.

What I guess you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\ihat}{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{\i}}}}
\newcommand{\jhat}{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{\j}}}}

\begin{document}

The position of an object is given by
$\mathbf{r} = (ct - bt^{3}) \ihat + dt^{2}\jhat$, with constants
$c = 6.7~\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$, $b = 0.81~\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^{3}$,
and $d = 4.5~\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Although you should maybe look into the `siunitx` package for typesetting units more easily.

The `siunitx` way. Note the use of `\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}` in the preamble to give you the solidus for "per", as opposed to, e.g. m s<sup>-3</sup>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\ihat}{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{\i}}}}
\newcommand{\jhat}{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{\j}}}}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

The position of an object is given by
$\mathbf{r} = (ct - bt^{3}) \ihat + dt^{2}\jhat$, with constants
$c = 6.7~\si{\metre\per\second}$,
$b = 0.81~\si{\metre\per\cubic\second}$, and
$d = 4.5~\si{\metre\per\square\second}$
```

Answer (score 4):

As people are saying the in comments, for boldface symbols in mathematics use `\mathbf` and drop the `\emph`. Also, math-mode `$...$` is designed for typesetting formulas, so keep the plus signs etc inside the dollar signs.

For units there is the really useful [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/) package. Using this I would typeset `b`, for example, as `$b=\SI{0.81}{m/s^3}$`.

If you are going to be using things like `\mathbf{\hat{i}}` a lot then it is worth defining a macro because this make the code both quicker to type and easier read and understand. The simplest macros are just substitutions:

```
\newcommand\bi{\mathbf{\hat{i}}}
```

but they can also take arguments (see, for example, [defining-macros-with-arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191266/defining-macros-with-arguments/191271#191271)).

Putting this together, I would type your MWE as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand\bi{\mathbf{\hat{i}}}
\newcommand\bj{\mathbf{\hat{j}}}
\newcommand\br{\mathbf{r}}

\begin{document}\noindent
The position of an object is given by
$\br = (ct - bt^3)\bi + dt^2\bj$,
with constants $c=\SI{6.7}{m/s}$,
$b=\SI{0.81}{m/s^3}$, and $d=\SI{4.5}{m/s^2}$.

\end{document}
```

to give

[image]

Comment: A comma is missing after the definition of $c$.